# Crontab not sending mail after error

Tags: python, linux, cron

I have a simple python test script that raises an exception when is executed.

```
raise FileExistsError
```

For calling this file a created a simple shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh
/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python /home/user/script.py
```

And I have the following task in crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
MAILTO=xxx@gmail.com


10 15 * * * /home/user/script.sh
10 15 * * * echo hi
```

But I am not receiving any mail after the python script has crashed! What is wrong in here?

Comment: Have you checked mail logs (probably `/var/log/mail.log`)? What probably has happened is that you haven't configured your computer to send emails correctly, so it is either not being sent, or getting rightly rejected by gmail's spam filter

Comment: I don't even have a mail.log file, so it might be something related to this

Comment: Any advice of what should I do?

Comment: Check which mail program your crond uses? Then check that program works for you? Check syslog for cron output?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.